# Package changes not taken, even after new name in Manifest

Tags: android

i made a little mistake, i published(started the process, now its waiting to publish) my app name with the first package i created, so i chose to change everything and publish again with the new name, but google play keep saying that the OLD is already in use, but i cant understand, i already made the changes and dont want to use the old...

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.HereComes.theNewPaCkage" >
```

but it keep saying that the old com.HereComes.TheOldPaCkage is already in use, if i open the project folder and try to search for the term TheOldPaCkage nothing shows, doesnt it mean that there is nO reference to the old package? why google keep saying that i want to use the old...

is there  any other file i have to change?

Comment: are you working on Android Studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this before.
In it's solution, what I have done is just remove the previous package from **Google Play**, then I tried to upload new one.

After that my problem was solved.

You can try this way.

Comment: so i need to wait the publish progress to do that ? hmmm thanks, =)

Comment: U need to un-publish the previous app and publish the new one, it will do everything for you